# Submodule of a semisimple module is just a subsum of decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a semsimple module and let $\{V_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a complete set of representatives of the isomorphism classes of simple modules. Let $M_i$ be the sum of all simple submodules isomorphic to $V_i$.

Now, if all the $M_i$ are finitely generated we have

$$M = \oplus m_i V_i$$

for suitable integers $m_i$.

Now, if $N$ is any submodule of $M$, then it too is semisimple ( I wish to show that $N$ is of the form

$$N = \oplus n_iV_i$$
for suitable integers $n_i \leq m_i$. Either $N \cap V_i = 0$ or $N \cap V_i = V_i$ since the $V_i$ are simple. Now, it is clear that $N$ can be projected onto the decomposition of $M$ which feels insufficient to state the result. Further, I believe if I assume $N$ is not in fact a sum of copies of the simple modules it contains, then there would have to be some other $W$ (at least one) such that $W$ is simple and $W \not \cong V_i$ for all $i$. I feel like this would force a composition series which is too long for $M$ hence $W$ must be 0 but have been unable to confirm my hunch. Can someone offer some hints?

Comment: Think of a vector space of rank 2 over a field $F$. It is of the form $F\oplus F$. However, there *are* rank 1 subspaces $L$ whose intersection with each of these copies of $F$ is 0. You appear to have missed this aspect. So you need to project $N$ "away" from all those (copies of) $V_i$ such that $V_i\cap N=0$. What will be left will be the copies of $V_i$ that are needed for $N$.

Comment: This is what's been bothering me. I'm thinking if I consider the set of all simple modules of $N$ such that they are isomorphic to a $V_i$ and then count those.

Comment: There are too many of those! Consider the example of the rank 2 vector space as above. So find a $V_i\subset M$ such that $V_i\cap N=0$ and project to $M/V_i$ (for this $V_i$). Repeat. Since $m_i$ is finite the process stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be a semsimple module and let $\{V_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a complete set of representatives of the isomorphism classes of simple modules. Let $M_i$ be the sum of all simple submodules isomorphic to $V_i$.

Now, if all the $M_i$ are finitely generated we have

$$M = \oplus m_i V_i$$

for suitable integers $m_i$.

Now, if $N$ is any submodule of $M$, then it too is semisimple. Notice that since the $M_i$ are finitely generated they are noetherian (the $M_i$ have a finite composition series) and so every submodule of the $M_i$ finitely generated. Define the $N_i$ similarly to the $M_i$ except for simple submodules of $N$ not $M$ (notice that all simple modules of $M$ give all the simple modules of $N$) and so similar to $M$ we have

$$N= \oplus N_i$$

Then, since the $N_i$ are finitely generated we have

$$N = \oplus n_i  V_i$$

for appropriate $n_i$ and $V_i$. We must have $n_i \leq m_i$ since

$$M \cong \oplus n_iV_i \oplus (m_i-n_i)V_i=N\oplus(m_i-n_i)V_i$$

and so if $n_i > m_i$ we would violate the length of $M$'s composition series. Finally, notice that this implies that $M/N \cong (m_i-n_i)V_i$.